# Find difference between two rows by usind Dax in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api, dax, business-intelligence

I have three column one is Id(ID is same) 2nd col is amount and third is date, I want difference between two rows(amount)

Comment: adding your sample data and explaining a bit about your desired result will be helpful to provide some ideas

Comment: Post some sample data and your desired results

Comment: Column1 101 , 101 , 101 Clumn2 512 , 510, 610, 480 now i want to subtract these column 2 values like 510-580=70 and 580-610=30

Answer (score 4):

As you want to have the previous value of the date where the ID is equal, you can use the following:

Add a column,

```
Column4 = 
    var baseFilter = FILTER(DiffRows;DiffRows[Column1] = EARLIER(DiffRows[Column1]))
    var selectDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE(DiffRows[Column3]);baseFilter; 
        FILTER(baseFilter; DiffRows[Column3] < EARLIER(DiffRows[Column3])))
 return 
     DiffRows[Column2] - CALCULATE(sum(DiffRows[Column2]);baseFilter; 
     FILTER(baseFilter; DiffRows[Column3] =selectDate))
```

First I create a basefilter to ensure the IDs are same.
Next I select the date whcih is the previousdate within the set of same ids
Last I use this date, to filter the correct value out of the rows.

End result:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer so it is confirmed answered